# Rails 3 routing with namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces

When trying to access the following URL, I get a **404 error page**:

> dev.mydomain.com/api

whereas my routes.rb file mentions that this route does exist:

#### routes.rb

```
constraints :subdomain => 'dev' do
  root :to => 'developers/main#index', :as => :developers
  namespace 'api', :as => :developers_api do
    root :to => 'developers/apidoc/main#index'
  end
end
```

#### rake routes

```
         developers   /(.:format)      {:subdomain=>"dev", :controller=>"developers/main", :action=>"index"}
developers_api_root   /api(.:format)   {:subdomain=>"dev", :controller=>"api/developers/apidoc/main", :action=>"index"}
```

#### controller

/app/controllers/developers/apidoc/main_controller.rb

```
class Developers::Apidoc::MainController < Developers::BaseController
  def index
  end
end
```

#### logs

```
[router]: GET dev.mydomain.com/api dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=14ms status=404 bytes=0
[web.1]: Started GET "/api"
[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::Developers)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that your route points to `api/developers/apidoc/main` but your class is only `Developers::Apidoc::MainController`.  You should either not namespace that route with `api` or add Api to the namespace of the controller - `Api::Developers::Apidoc::MainController`.

Answer (score 3):

Another important factor to keep in mind is that route namespaces need accompanying directory paths to be consistent. Getting this wrong will also cause an error like this:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant Api::Developers
```

In my case, I had a route structure like this:

```
namespace "api" do
  namespace "developers" do
    ...
  end
end
```

and the folder/directory structure should have been **app/controllers/api/developers/**

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Replace `namespace` with `scope`

Given the following folder structure

```
 Rails.root
  |
  +-- app/
  |    |
  |    +-- controllers/
  |         |
  |         +-- jobs_controller.rb
  +-- config/
       |
       +-- routes.rb
```

the snippet below in `routes.rb` gives an error `ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant Api:`

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :jobs
  end
end
```

while the following works:

```
scope :api do
  scope :v1 do
    resources :jobs 
  end
end
```

The reason is briefly mentioned at [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers):

> The *namespace* scope will automatically add `:as` as well as
>   `:module` and `:path` prefixes.

And indeed, namespace is just a wrapper around scope with a bunch of predefined options:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb, line 871
def namespace(path, options = {})
  path = path.to_s

  defaults = {
    module:         path,
    path:           options.fetch(:path, path),
    as:             options.fetch(:as, path),
    shallow_path:   options.fetch(:path, path),
    shallow_prefix: options.fetch(:as, path)
  }

  scope(defaults.merge!(options)) { yield }
end
```